# Best way to add and install runtime dependency to an existing package in Nix?

Tags: nix

Installing package in Nix with `nix-env -i <pkg>` and adding Nix environment with `source ~/.nix-profile/etc/profile.d/nix.sh` causes that package to appear on top of the `$PATH` which is usually desirable.

What if I want to install and specify a runtime dependency (e.g. `python` or `perl` interpreter) for already existing package but don't want the dependency to appear for the rest of packages and system environment?

In my case I want to add `perl` dependency to [fzf package](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/1694c0b3f7ab9416f266e719001f74116878e1fa/pkgs/tools/misc/fzf/default.nix) as it uses perl [here](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/e6d33f77da8cc36786c814f499f6cb3405e8c4c1/shell/key-bindings.zsh#L103). But I don't want it to be present for the rest of the system for compatibility reasons.

I tried overriding `fzf` with `packageOverrides` but first it seems to work only for build dependencies and second there is no argument to specify `perl`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you'd use [wrapProgram](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#ssec-stdenv-functions) to replace an executable by a script that modifies `PATH` before invoking the real executable.

In this case it's a bit more complicated, because it's not a standalone program but a script to be imported, so it can not use a wrapper. In `postInstall` you could use [substituteInPlace](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#ssec-stdenv-functions), which will look somewhat like

```
substituteInPlace $out/path-to-keybindings.zsh --replace '| perl ' '| ${pkgs.perl}/bin/perl '
```

This will patch the script to reference perl by its absolute store path, without modifying the environment.

Comment: Thanks @RobertHensing! Seems like should work. Unfortunately have different problem which stops me from testing the solution. Does mentioning `${pkgs.perl}` install it in the store but not make it entirely visible to the environment?

Comment: That is correct. It only does the minimum to make it work. `"${pkgs.perl}"` evaluates to a store path and the `substituteInPlace` command puts that store path in the file in the output. Perl therefore becomes part of the closure, but `nix-env` does not look any deeper than the derivations that are passed directly to it, so Perl will not be added to `PATH` because of this `"${pkgs.perl}"`.